# Help with script computing Galois Groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory, computer-science, computer-algebra-systems, sagemath

I've been developing (see below) a script on how to calculate Galois groups using a statistical method. However, when I try to run the code for degree >_ 10 on cocalc (SageMathCloud), I end up with an error stating:

f = x^11 + 25*x^4 + 39
There are 348511 primes less than 5000000 which do not divide disc(f)
cycle type (2, 3, 5) occurs 11601 times,ieError in lines 27-31
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/projects/sage/sage-7.6/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/smc_sagews/sage_server.py", line 995, in execute
    exec compile(block+'\n', '', 'single') in namespace, locals
  File "", line 5, in 
NameError: name 'numerical' is not defined

I was hoping if someone could potentially help me to ensure that the script is working properly - I just would like to play around with this and see what the weaknesses are with this script.

```
R.<x>=ZZ[x];
f=;
y =
print "f =", f;
if f.is_irreducible()==true:
    L=[];
    for i in range (y):
        if is_prime(i)==true:
            if disc(f)%i!=0:
                k=f.change_ring(GF(i)).factor();
                l=[];
                for j in range(len(k)):
                    if k[j][1]*k[j][0].degree()>=2:
                        l.append(k[j][1]*k[j][0].degree());
                L.append(tuple(l));
c=len(L);
print "There are",c, "primes less than",y, "which do not divide disc(f)";
S=Set(L)
v=0;
for r in range(len(S)):
    if S[r]==():
        v=1;
        h=L.count(S[r]);
        o=numerical_approx(c/h,digits=1);
        print "The order of G is", o
        print "Identity occurs", L.count(S[r]), "times, ie:" ,RealField(2)    (L.count(S[r])*100/c), "%";
for r in range(len(S)):
        if S[r]!=():
            if v==1:
                print "cycle type",S[r], "occurs", L.count(S[r]),"times,ie:",numerical_approx(L.count(S[r])*100/c,digits=2),"%","n",S[r],"=",numerical_approx(L.count(S[r])/h,digits=1);
            else:print "cycle type", S[r], "occurs",L.count(S[r]), "times,ie",numerical_approx(L.count(S[r])*100/c,digits=2),"%";
```

Thank you and have a good day. :-)

[image: Script-fails-for-higher]

Comment: Who is  the author of the code or method? Is there a link for the source of the algorithm? I think that should be edited into the question.

Comment: The indentation on your code is really mangled in the last few lines.  You should fix it.  Also, you have a curly brace in S[r}, which I'm guessing is unintentional.

Comment: The indentation is still messed up.  The last `else` on the last line corresponds to the `if f.is_irreducible()==true:`.

Answer (score 4):

This may still have some problems, but it now runs successfully for me.  Changes are on lines 13 and 14 in the tuples replace the letter "l" with the digit "1"  On line 24 replace digits=0 with digits = 1 Fix indentation on lines 30ff.  Finally replace the "." with a "," in L.count(S[r])*100/c.digits=2 around line 30

```
R.<x>=ZZ[x];
f=x^5-7*x+1;
y = 1000000
print "f =", f;
if f.is_irreducible()==true:
    L=[];
    for i in range (y):
        if is_prime(i)==true:
            if disc(f)%i!=0:
                k=f.change_ring(GF(i)).factor();
                l=[];
                for j in range(len(k)):
                    if k[j][1]*k[j][0].degree()>=2:
                        l.append(k[j][1]*k[j][0].degree());
                L.append(tuple(l));
c=len(L);
print "There are",c, "primes less than",y, "which do not divide disc(f)";
S=Set(L)
v=0;
for r in range(len(S)):
    if S[r]==():
        v=1;
        h=L.count(S[r]);
        o=numerical_approx(c/h,digits=1);
        print "The order of G is", o
        print "Identity occurs", L.count(S[r]), "times, ie:" ,RealField(2)    (L.count(S[r])*100/c), "%";
for r in range(len(S)):
        if S[r]!=():
            if v==1:
                print "cycle type",S[r], "occurs", L.count(S[r]),"times,ie:",numerical_approx(L.count(S[r])*100/c,digits=2),"%","n",S[r],"=",numerical_approx(L.count(S[r])/h,digits=1);
                else:print "cycle type", S[r], "occurs",L.count(S[r]), "times,ie",numerical_approx(L.count(S[r])*100/c,digits=2),"%";
else:print "is not irreducible in ZZ[x]";
```

Comment: Error in lines 27-32
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/projects/sage/sage-7.6/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/smc_sagews/sage_server.py", line 995, in execute
    exec compile(block+'\n', '', 'single') in namespace, locals
  File "<string>", line 5
    else:print "cycle type", S[r], "occurs",L.count(S[r]),     "times,ie",numerical.approx(L.count(S[r])*Integer(100)/c,digits=Integer(2)),"%";
       ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: @AlwaysNeedHelp  You need to check the indentation and spacing carefully on lines 30 ff.  The script runs without errors for me.  The first else:print aligns with print on the previous line.  The second else:print should align with if S[r]!=() 4 lines above.  Where did that "Integer(2)" and Integer(100) come from?  Are those just from the debug output?

Comment: Thank you for your helpful comments. I'm almost there (I've got the cycle types showing. One final problem I'm facing is that one of the lines does not seem to fit together, spilling over onto the next line and hence does not execute the final part of the code. I've tried to put the code on a single line, but it does not seem to allow me to do so (this is on cocalc.com). I may be able to show you via a photo (I will edit it in the original post). Very much appreciative of all your help.

Comment: @AlwaysNeedHelp on line 30 remove the line break between the print line and the else:print line

Comment: Hi, did that. Now the last line has a problem: (code is pasted into sagecell.sagemath.org) - Please see original post for picture. 

If I remove the last line, it does most of the script, but then repeats the last cycle and calculation. So it's almost there!

Comment: @AlwaysNeedHelp the code I posted runs successfully. How does your code differ?

Comment: If I copy and paste your code directly into https://sagecell.sagemath.org/
I obtain this error: 

 File "<ipython-input-1-5d1a22d38802>", line 31
    else:print "cycle type", S[r], "occurs",L.count(S[r]),"times,ie",numerical.approx(L.count(S[r])*Integer(100)/c,digits=Integer(2)),"%";
       ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

This is simply just taking the code from your post and plugging it straight in (please see original post) - really sorry about all the trouble caused. All I did was to remove the break from line 30 and 31 as you said before. Have you altered the code in your post?

Comment: @AlwaysNeedHelp I have recopied the last 6 lines from a running sage workbook.  There may be problems with the indentation and line breaks when copying/pasting, and, additionally, there may be some non-printing characters embedded in the code.  Edit your code to agree with my post.

Comment: @sharding4 Did you understand what it does ? If factors the polynomial $f$ over several finite fields $\mathbf{F}_q$, then what ?

Comment: @reuns  the idea is based on the Tchebotarev Density Theorem.  The degrees of the irreducible factors correspond to cycles.  So take $x^3-2$ say.  Factoring modulo 5 gives a linear and a quadratic factor which corresponds to a cycle type (1,2).  Modulo 7 the polynomial is irreducible so corresponds to a 3-cycle.  Module 31 the polynomial splits completely so correspinds to the identity.  The script counts the factorizations and estimates the frequencies of the various cycle types.  In the example script provided the y =10000 is too low and will give an incorrect answer.  y=10^6 is needed.

Comment: That's what I understand from your comment : Given $G = Gal(K/\mathbb{Q})$ with $K$ the splitting field of $f \in \mathbb{Q}[x]$, we have the map $p \mapsto G^{-1} \phi_p G = \{ \sigma^{-1} \phi_p \sigma, \sigma \in G\}$ where $\phi_p \in G$ is the Frobenius automorphism such that for some prime $\mathfrak{p}$ above $p$ : 
$$\forall a \in K, a^p \equiv \phi_p(a) \bmod \mathfrak{p}, \qquad 
a^p\equiv \sigma^{-1}(\phi_p(\sigma(a)) \bmod \sigma^{-1}(\mathfrak{p})$$

Comment: We also have the map $G^{-1}\phi G\mapsto Type(\phi)$ the cycle type of $\phi$ acting on the roots of $f$.
From an effective version of Chebotarev density theorem, factoring $f$ over several primes $p$, we can find $Type(G) = \{ |G^{-1} \phi G|,  Type(\phi), \phi \in G\}$. Is it enough to recover the $S_n$ representation of $G$ ?

Comment: @reuns  it is enough to recover $G$ in some cases, but I don't believe it is very efficient.  The bounds can be very high in terns of how many primes need to be tested.  By comparison looking for cycle structures using some theory such as "for $n ≥ 2$, a transitive subgroup of $S_n$ that contains a transposition and a $p$-cycle for some prime $p > n/2$ is $S_n$" can be very effective,

Comment: What I wrote is the same as recovering $G$ from its character table ?

Comment: @reuns  I'm not sure, but I think you should be able to distinguish $D_8$ from $Q_8$ as Galois groups using statistical analysis, but you can't distinguish them from their character tables.

Comment: @sharding4

Just wanted to thank you - I got the script to work in the end. However, when I begin to try to look at deg >_ 11 polynomials, I begin to encounter errors such as (see original post). Do you know of any possible way to remedy this?

Comment: @AlwaysNeedHelp  Two things.  Look at the first else:print line.  One of the numerical_approx has numerical.approx instead.  Second there are much better ways to show that the Galois group of that polynomial is $S_{11}$  For example the use theorem "for $n ≥ 2$, a transitive subgroup of $S_n$ that contains a transposition and an $(n − 1)$-cycle is $S_n$."   Looking at your polynomial modulo 7 shows that there is a 10 cycle.   Modulo 47 is of cycle type $(1,1,2,7)$ whose $7^{th}$ power will be a transposition.